# How can I display the results of this javascript snippet in a browser window?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm fine with understanding what is happening in the console.log but I want to display the code in the browser window. I think I should use document.write but I am unsure about this.

```
var friends = {
bill: {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
},
steve: {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Gates",
}
};

var list = function(friends){
for (var key in friends){
    console.log(key);
}
};

var search = function(name){
for (var key in friends){
     if (friends[key].firstName === name){
    console.log(friends[key]);
    return friends[key];
    }   
}
};
```

Comment: I'd recommend creating an element on the page, then using "element.innerHTML = stuff" to put it on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `alert` function

```
alert("Hello World")
```

or you could use

```
document.write("Hello World")
```

which outputs the string "Hello World" to the position of the js snippet in the html. Alternatively, you could manipulate the DOM and set [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) on a `div` or `span` tag. If you add a tag with an id to your html like so,

```
<span id="foo"></span>
```

you can set the html contents with

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "Hello World"
```

Of course, if your problem is to serialize the result of your function, use [`JSON.Stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
alert(JSON.stringify({"hello": "world", 3: "bar"}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to show your *hash* you can use document.write, but you need to "stringify" your data like that :

```
document.write(JSON.Stringify(friends));`
```

And if you would like something more beautiful :

```
document.write(JSON.stringify(friends, null, "<br/>"))
```

Documentation :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use jQuery's .html() to modify an existing HTML element on your page.

```
var showFriends=function(){
var x = JSON.stringify(friends,null,'</br>');
$('#myDiv').html('<p>'+x+'</p>');
};
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLZff/